# unbound method with "enum-like" class

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
ff = lambda x : x
gg = lambda x : x*2
class FunctionCollection(object):
    f = ff
    g = gg

def FunctionCaller(x, Type = FunctionCollection.f):
    return Type(x)

y = FunctionCaller(x)
```

It returns an

> unbound method () must be called with FunctionCollection instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)

message which I don't understand.
An obvious solution would be define ff and gg INSIDE FunctionCollection, but I would like to know if it is not possible to define ff and gg in a module, then create an enum containing the "pointers" to those function, and finally pass those "pointers" as arguments. Sorry for the C-style naming.

What's wrong with that?

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: "An obvious solution would be define ff and gg INSIDE FunctionCollection" - nope, wouldn't help.

Comment: in `y = FunctionCaller(x)`, where has `x` been defined?

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually *does* work on python3.x.  If you need to support python2.x, you can use a staticmethod:

```
ff = lambda x : x
gg = lambda x : x*2
class FunctionCollection(object):
    f = staticmethod(ff)
    g = staticmethod(gg)

def FunctionCaller(x, Type = FunctionCollection.f):
    return Type(x)

y = FunctionCaller(1.0)
print(y)
```

---

Another option would be to use `FunctionCollection` as a "singleton" and bind the functions to the single instance...

```
ff = lambda x : x
gg = lambda x : x*2
class FunctionCollection(object):
    pass

FUNC_COLLECTION = FunctionCollection()
FUNC_COLLECTION.f = ff
FUNC_COLLECTION.g = gg


def FunctionCaller(x, Type = FUNC_COLLECTION.f):
    return Type(x)

y = FunctionCaller(1.0)
print(y)
```

---

> I would like to know if it is not possible to define ff and gg in a module, then create an enum containing the "pointers" to those function, and finally pass those "pointers" as arguments.

I think that this begs an obvious question ... Why do you need this additional level of indirection?  It seems unnecessary to me<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>which is certainly not to say that it *is* unnecessary -- just that I don't understand the purpose as of yet ...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for both answers! Actually you are right, there is NO real reason for an additional indirection. I simply wrote all the functions in the main module, and eventually thought it could be useful to have them all as static method of a class. Before migrating the code, I tried the "fast way" and I got stuck, hence my question... :-)